# Join on each possible combination for each group

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables

```
T1
order1      grp
----------- -----------
1           1
2           1
3           1
4           1
1           2
2           2
3           2

T2
order1      count1      abbrev grp
----------- ----------- ------ -----------
2           5           A      1
1           17          B      2
2           11          B      2
```

The tables are joined this way:

```
SELECT 
  t2.grp, t2.order1, t2.count1, t2.abbrev 
FROM t2 
JOIN t1
ON
  t1.grp = t2.grp and
  t1.order1 = t2.order1
```

Result:

```
grp         order1      count1      abbrev
----------- ----------- ----------- ------
1           2           5           A
2           1           17          B
2           2           11          B
```

Problem is that i need a row for each possible combination for each group:

```
grp         order1      count1      abbrev
----------- ----------- ----------- ------
1           1           0           A
1           2           5           A
1           3           0           A
1           4           0           A
2           1           17          B
2           2           11          B
2           3           0           B
```

Comment: If you had `abbrev = C` for the `grp = 1, order = 2`, what would the result look like?

Comment: You should normalise the data so that the groups are in a separate table.

Comment: group and abbrev goes hand in hand, one is the leading text in my the situation i encounted, the other is the id for that text.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: your model is not normalized then. Replace `JOIN` with `RIGHT JOIN`, throw an `OUTER APPLY` to select `abbrev` for missing rows and warp the output fields into `COALESCE`.

Comment: Quassnoi this is how the data in this system is stored. It is to store data for questionaries. If i change 1 comma in any tables we lose all support on the entire system. The original question was much more complex, but I took the essential and boilded it down to make it readable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  cube.grp,
  cube.order,
  ISNULL(data.count, 0),
  chars.abbrev
FROM
  @t1   AS cube
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT grp, abbrev FROM @t2 GROUP BY grp, abbrev) AS chars
    ON chars.grp = cube.grp
LEFT JOIN
  @t2   AS data
    ON  data.grp    = cube.grp
    AND data.order  = cube.order
    AND data.abbrev = chars.abbrev
```